# DropZone.js server side validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, webforms, dropzone.js

I'm doing server side validation for the files uploaded.  Not every file that makes it to the server is stored.  How can I display/trigger the error on the file(s) that were not successfully stored on the server.  I've tried adding a server Validation function but can't figure out how to do it... Please help

```
                  this.on("successmultiple", function (file, successResponse) {
                        uploadResult = eval(successResponse);
                        toastr.options.positionClass = "toast-bottom-right";
                        var ErrorMessage = "";
                        for (var i = 0; i < uploadResult.ResultList.length; i++) {
                            var result = uploadResult.ResultList[i];
                            if (result.IsSuccessful === "True") {
                                toastr.success(result.Message);
                                if (hdnFileIDList !== "")
                                    hdnFileIDList = hdnFileIDList + "|" + result.ID;
                                else
                                    hdnFileIDList = result.ID
                            }
                            else {
                                //-- trigger dropzone error
                                toastr.warning(result.Message);
                                //this.ValidationError(file, result.Message);
                                file.accepted = false;
                                file.status = Dropzone.ERROR;
                                dropzone.serverError(file, result.Message);
                                //dropzone.emit("errormultiple", file, result.Message);
                            }                                
                        }
                        $("#<%=hdnSharedFileObjNewFileIDList.clientID%>").val(hdnFileIDList);
                    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved my problem by adding the following code to Dropzone.js then calling it from my "successmultiple" event when I see and error in my returned JSON from the server.

```
 Dropzone.prototype.serverError = function (file, message) {
                file.accepted = false;
                file.status = Dropzone.ERROR;
                return this._errorProcessing(file, message);
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else that's landed here after searching for a solution to this problem: there's a pretty simple and elegant way to deal with this without getting into the guts of Dropzone. If your server side validation fails, return a status code of 400 (bad request) and include your error message as a jsonResponse.

Then you can handle the response with something like the following code in your dropzone's init configuration (assuming you are sending your error message as "ValidationMessage"):

```
this.on("error", function (file, jsonResponse) {
    var errorMessage = "Could not upload document: ";
    if (jsonResponse["ValidationMessage"] != null) {
        errorMessage += jsonResponse["ValidationMessage"];
    } else {
        errorMessage += "unknown error";
    }
    alert(errorMessage);
});
```

The file will have a big red X on it just like a regular Dropzone failed upload.

This solution is for single uploads rather than multiple but the same idea should work for multiple.